# Regex to "ignore" not "exclude"

Tags: regex, thunderbird

I'm totally lost. I need a regular expression that
can detect any of the 4 starting urls like below

```
 ^(.*http://.*|.*http%3A%2F%2F.*|.*https://.*|.*https%3A%2F%2F.*)$
```

And ... .

should detect:
(any punctuation or space or backspace)(3 times the letter w in upper or lower case)(one dot)(anything)

And ... . which is important

Should Ignore, but NOT Exclude... . the following exact string (either it's present in the page or not)

```
 http://www.w3.org
```

Which is complicated for me, because i still need to include it in the regex line
even if it's ignored, otherwise, it will match & be found in

```
    (.*http://.*|.*http%3A%2F%2F.*|.*https://.*|.*https%3A%2F%2F.*)
```

And my aim is to find/match any url besides

```
    http://www.w3.org
```

even if it's in the page, Or if it's not present.
so if there's only this in the page:

```
    http://www.w3.org
```

& no other url.. then it shouldn't match.

---

Thanks Tyler but my regex knowledge is almost zero, i can only know what commands do when i right click on them to chose actions like in regulazy or regexr  ((

So i updated my command according to the url i provided to you:
href%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Edommermuth%2D1%2Ecom
& it works:

https?(://|%3A%2F%2F)(?!www.w3.org)(.*)

But because of my lack of knowledge, i don't understand how to do that below

"What you could do is make the http part optional, or must match http or www or both. This type of regex came up in another question I answered recently - Multiple preg_replace RegEx for different URLs"

I tried to add this, but it doesn't work:
(www.)

All i'm missing now is detection of urls starting with www

(any punctuation or space or backspace)(3 times the letter w in upper or lower case)(one dot)(anything till it reaches a space or the end of a line)

Comment: Don't link to posts on another site (they tend to expire). Learn to simply format your questions correctly (URLs in *code* don't count as links).

Comment: Do you need it to be all in 1 regex? Why not combining 2 regex, first one to match and second one to exclude? Which coding language are you using?

Comment: I don't understand your distinction between "ignore" and "exclude". You want to write a regex that matches a certain format of urls but _does not match_ the w3 one. To me, that's still exclusion.

Comment: .Net regex right? If so add it to the question tags.

Comment: Or you could eventually try to fix this if possible, i modified my command: http://regexr.com/v1?38kmv

Comment: @user3451630 Can you give us actual example(s) of raw text with what needs to be matched within that text and what should be excluded?

Comment: Omegaman, i gave you the examples in the regex url above, please read it

Answer (score 2):

OK so try this:

```
/\bhttps?(://|%3A%2F%2F)(?!www\.w3\.org)(.*)\b/g
```

Test here: http://regexr.com?38jp5

That test link uses javascript-style regex, but should work elsewhere.

The important part is the second half - a negative lookahead, that checks what follows is *not* the exact text `www.w3.org`

I compressed what you had: mine matches `http` then an optional `s` then either `://` or `%3A%2F%2F`.

I wrapped the whole thing in word boundaries, you could change that to quotes or whatever you need. The global flag lets you match multiple items.

---

In regards to OP's questions:

> D%22
>   could appear before http or https
>
> this one is missing & should match:
>   href%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Edommermuth%2D1%2Ecom

If this matters, just remove the word boundary `\b` before and after the regex, so the http can match anywhere.

> The regex command should detect: (any punctuation or space or backspace)(3 times the letter w in upper or lower case)(one dot)(anything)

This regex would fail to match a link like http://google.com - looking for www is really not a good way to check for a link on its own. What you could do is make the http part optional, or must match http or www or both. This type of regex came up in another question I answered recently - [Multiple preg_replace RegEx for different URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22591369/multiple-preg-replace-regex-for-different-urls/22591944#22591944)

---

Edit #2:

> (any punctuation or space or backspace)(3 times the letter w in upper or lower case)(one dot)(anything till it reaches a space or the end of a line)

As I mention above, what you are describing will not match a url like http://google.com - but if that is what you want, use this:

```
(\W|^)[wW]{3}\.[^\s$]+
```

Instead of that, what I think you want is this, which is a combination of my first answer, and the link to a different post above.

```
((https?(://|%3A%2F%2F))(www\.)|(https?(://|%3A%2F%2F))|(www\.))(?!(www\.)?w3\.org)([^</\?\s]+)[^<\s]*
```

You'll want to use this regex with the Global and Insensitive flags

Comment: Note that this is slightly more relaxed that the OP's, and would match `https%3A/%2F...`. To be equivalent, you'd want `https?(://|%3A%2F%2F)`

Comment: For completeness, you should escape the .'s - otherwise, that also ignores wwwxw3.org. It's not clear what this is being used for, but this type of omission is where subtle bugs and security vulnerabilities come from.

Comment: Thanks for catching that @gregmac - updated the regex and the link

Comment: @user3451630 `wye.cg/ye3` should *not* match, because it does not follow any of the rules you gave me. It does not start with http or www, which is what you are using for finding a link. I don't know what rules you are now trying to use.

Comment: Here's my final command with one error, explained here: http://regexr.com/v1?38kmp

Comment: @user3451630 I think you're trying to do something that Regex is not designed for. Regex needs a very strict pattern to match against, which is fine for matching `http` or `www`. But a regex cannot decide if a url is valid or not without a strict rule. For example, you want to match `ww2.deee.eee` but not `www2.dzede.eeex` - both of those are theoretically valid URLs. You're going to run into so many weird cases where you miss a url or get a false positive with these random edge cases you're trying to match.

Comment: Yes, with a strict rule like "the exact text w3.org must not appear", regex will work. But what is the exact rule you want to use here? What exactly about `wye.cg/ye3` do you want to match?

Comment: Thats exactly what I said above: "You're going to run into so many weird cases where you miss a url ...". Why should lodezeldeed.com match? Its not supposed to, it doesn't match the rules you gave me.

Comment: /i is a flag and must appear at the end of your regex. http://regexr.com/v1?38ko3.

Comment: Its difficult to tell what you have tried and what is not working, and it seems to not be related to the original question. I would suggest asking a new question, including the minimum examples to reproduce your new problem, and what you have tried yourself, so that the rest of the SO community can help as well.

Comment: I am really confused by what you want. Regex is a matching engine, it sounds like what you're trying to do would work better from code. I still think that deserves a new question. Don't copy the explanation, you should just limit the question to this new problem. Provide the related code you are using, what the code should do, and what the code does not do.